# How to combine two firestore queries in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to combine two firestore queries from the same collection. I want the result combination to be a `Query`.

```
var a = lessons
    .withConverter<Lesson>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Lesson.fromFirestore(snapshot),
      toFirestore: (Lesson lesson, options) => lesson.toFirestore(),
    )
    .where('private', isEqualTo: false);

var b = lessons
    .withConverter<Lesson>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Lesson.fromFirestore(snapshot),
      toFirestore: (Lesson lesson, options) => lesson.toFirestore(),
    )
    .where('private', isEqualTo: true)
    .where('author', isEqualTo: uid);
```

The first query gets all public lessons regardless of the author, the second query only gets the private lessons that the user created. I would then like to combine those results or create a union of the results.

I'm relatively new to flutter firestore, I've looked for some solutions online but I couldn't find one that fits my specific scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new [OR capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) of Firestore to put this in a single query. The most literal translation would look like this:

```
lessons.where(
  Filter.or(
    Filter("public", isEqualTo: true),
    Filter.and(
      Filter("author", isEqualTo: user.uid),
      Filter("public", isEqualTo: false)
    )
  )
)
```

Since your `public` is a boolean, it can only be `true` or `false`, you can rewrite the above to this shorter form:

```
lessons.where(
  Filter.or(
    Filter("author", isEqualTo: user.uid),
    Filter("public", isEqualTo: true)
  )
)
```

The results for both are guaranteed to be the same, so I'd go for the latter, shorter query.

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting an error. I'm getting `Undefined name 'Filter'`. I went on to check the link you provided and there is no snippet available for `Dart`.

Comment: I tested this code here: https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-or-queries-zt72064mt730?entry=lib%2Fmain.dart. The `OR` capabilities are new, so you likely need to upgrade to a newer SDK version.

Comment: I was using the old packages of Firebase, but now everything is working fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var uid = 'your_user_id';

var query = lessons
  .withConverter<Lesson>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Lesson.fromFirestore(snapshot),
    toFirestore: (Lesson lesson, options) => lesson.toFirestore(),
  )
  .where('private', whereIn: [false, true])
  .where('author', isEqualTo: uid);
```

Comment: The first query gets all public lessons regardless of the author, the second query only gets the private lessons that the user created. I would then like to combine those results or create a union. With your approach, I would only get public and private lessons that the user creates.